# Preventing Excel 2010 to open documents over HTTP in Design Mode

Tags: excel-2010, excel-2013

It seems that when Excel 2010 or Excel 2013 opens over HTTP  a workbook that contains a macro then it automatically switches to Design Mode. Is there a way to prenvent this ? I have tried many options of the confidentiality center but none seems to solve the problem.

What I mean by "over HTTP" is that Excel accesses the spreadsheet through a HTTP URL. In our case, the workbook is stored on AWS S3 and accessed through cloudfront.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft:

"This is caused by opening a file that is designed to run macros, and macros have not been enabled.
To enable macros, go to Tools®Macro, Security tab and set Macro security to medium (recommended if you know that the files you receive are from trusted sources) or low (recommended only for advanced users or for users who only use files internal to their company).

As a person who develops macros, you can keep Design view from opening when users open your files, whether they enable macros or not, by closing Design view on the Control Toolbox before saving your file."
Source: http://www.officearticles.com/misc/file_opens_in_design_mode_in_microsoft_office.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Our security level is set at low and the workbook are not in desig mode when saved.